# Range of the interactions: long/short-range

Tags: quantum-mechanics, terminology, scattering, many-body, interactions

I have seen in [Long/short-range interaction](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/43140/long-short-range-interaction) that in scattering theory $^{−}$ is a short range potential for $n>1$ and a long range potential for $n\leq1$.

Now, why do we say that van-der-Waals and dipole-dipole are long range if they have the form $^{−}$ with $n=3,6$ respectively?

Comment: But $1/r^n$ is long range. It has scale symmetry.

Comment: "Short" and "long" are conventional and inexact terms (and different conventions are used in different areas). In this case, the forces are long-range because they (approximately) obey a power law: short-range would be exponentially decreasing forces.

Comment: Yes, not very clear. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- What constitutes a long range as opposed to short range interaction depends primarily on the specific problem under investigation.
- One finds many definitions in the literature; usually criteria can be expressed through the 2-body interaction potential $V(r)$.
- $V(r) \propto r^{-\alpha}$, with $\alpha \leq$ dimensions is considered a standard definition for long-range interactions. Dipolar interactions in a Bose-Einstein condensates are long-range by this definition.
- Also, if $V(r)$ falls off slower than exponentially, correlations are then qualitatively different and are often considered as long range in some contexts. Van der Waals interactions fall into this category.